# database slow after changing collation

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, collation, latin1

I changed the collation of the database from latin1_swedish_ci to utf8_general_ci and now there is huge impact on the performance. I am running this in local host and the queries seem to take a lot of time to execute as opposed to earlier. I am using PDO for database interactive activities. I can't seem to find any reason why this might be happening, are there any solutions for this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not provide information on the queries or tables being used, so this is speculation.

Changing the collation on the database does not change the collation on objects already created.  So, you probably have a mix of collations in your queries.  Such a mix can actually prevent the use of indexes, when they would otherwise be used.

To fix this, you would need to recreate all the objects in the database (including indexes) to use the new collation.

Here is another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/637148/how-does-mysql-use-collations-with-indexes) about this topic.

Comment: Thanks. You are right I had a mix of both collations and that might have caused this issue. I changed all objects to UTF8 & that solved the problem.